# jQuery post causes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I found a bunch of similar questions here but after 3 hours of reading them and trying stuff, I am posting my own. I apologize for the duplication, but I just don't know what's going on here.

So I have this javascript function:

```
function saveSetting(settingName, settingValue) {
    $.post(
        appUrl + "Account/SaveSetting",
        { settingName: settingName, settingValue: settingValue },
        function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

which I call like this:

```
saveSetting("bookFontSize", fontSize);
```

where fontSize is "10.5" or something similar.

Chrome reports the post headers like this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1227/Account/SaveSetting?callback=jQuery151022712289774790406_1298625531801
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:42
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=jwpzp4okerckuh2bhkl2pnwu; .ASPXAUTH=429EEA1CFBFD9D5702011C59F77F18F8DAEEEB412314D608E86289779DF8ED9C80C6E0370B7108D68C44B088C7CB6998F34C59DDCFF8EA9D4A556495F5D40DF21737392DCF5942F73726882BEC354C35599864F751751FD458473FA4541AF25294F7E16DC00AABD4DEC43B321B0ECCBF195FD419C3BC912017275FC478A27F0C12A28D124A663EA5F19E5AEFFB276603
Host:localhost:1227
Origin:http://localhost:1227
Referer:http://localhost:1227/Read/116/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.98 Safari/534.13
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
callback:jQuery151022712289774790406_1298625531801
Form Data
settingName:bookFontSize
settingValue:10.5
Response Headers
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Connection:Close
Content-Length:38
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 25 Feb 2011 09:18:53 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
```

That goes to a C# / ASP.NET MVC3 action that looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult SaveSetting(string settingName, string settingValue)
{
    try
    {
        repository.SaveSettingForUser(CurrentUser, settingName, settingValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = CurrentUser.IsAdmin() ? "Failed :" + ex.Message : "Failed" });
    }
    return Json(new { Result = string.Format("Set {0} to {1}.", settingName, settingValue) });
}
```

which, according to chrome, returns this:

```
{"Result":"Set bookFontSize to 10.5."}
```

which looks like legitimate json to me. However, I get this error in chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and this one in IE 7, and 8:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 67456553
Char: 10
Error: Expected ';'
Code: 0
URL: http://localhost:1227/Read/116/1
```

I definitely do not have 67 million lines of code :)

Anyway, does anyone know what the heck is going on here? My alert does not run. IE never actually gets the request out, but Chrome does.

I think this function actually worked with a previous version of jQuery a long time ago, with the setting `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true`, but now it doesn't work (jQuery 1.5.1) with or without that setting.

**Update**: I got it working. I stepped through the javascript with the debugger. For some reason, during the .ajax() call in jQuery, it was stepping into jquery.validate.js. Why would it do that? I had the file included, but was not using it anywhere. I eliminated the error by simply no longer referencing jquery.validate.js. But this kind of sucks, because what if I want to use the validation features in the future?

**So my question now is "Why does having jquery.validate.js in my project screw everything up?"**

**Update 2**: There is a bug in jquery.validate.js, which has now been fixed in a fork of that project on github. See my answer for details. I was not even *using* the validation features of that file, merely including it in the page for later use. It gets in the way and breaks things. Note from the author of jquery.validate.js regarding the fix: "Fixes jQuery 1.5- code by using jQuery.ajaxSettings and not window.ajaxSettings (yeah, that was dumb)."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out!!!

It's a bug in jquery.validate.js. It's repeated and documented here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8064

The author has addressed the issue on February 2, 2011, but this fix has not yet made it into an official release of the plugin (as of February 25, 2011 and jQuery Validate 1.7). If you would like jQuery 1.5+ JSON to work while using jquery validation, you should download the patched validation plugin.

https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-validation/raw/master/jquery.validate.js
https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-validation/raw/master/jquery.validate.min.js

If you are here from google and the above links don't work anymore, upgrading to a version of validate that is greater than 1.7 will probably work. Alternatively, go here https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-validation and grab the latest version from the repository.

2011-08-31 Update: It looks like they don't use that GitHub link anymore. [I *think* this is what you need.](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Awesome find. You saved me several hours.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the post as json, so the result must be auto evaluated.

Nevertheless, try to evaluate the result before the alert on inside the brackets of the alert

```
eval(data.Result)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the object key names are being set dynamically in some browsers? Try changing saveSetting to the following:

```
function saveSetting(settingName, settingValue) {
    $.post(
        appUrl + "Account/SaveSetting",
        { "settingName": settingName, "settingValue": settingValue },
        function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

Or perhaps changing the argument name to something other than the object key name:

```
function saveSetting(settingNameArg, settingValueArg) {
    $.post(
        appUrl + "Account/SaveSetting",
        { settingName: settingNameArg, settingValue: settingValueArg },
        function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

Comment: These were easy to try so I went for yours first! Unfortunately, neither helped. Also, I tried both simultaneously :)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning incorrect JSON from server. Your returned JSON has some control character in the `Result`. Would recommend sending a string without `new String.format`

Comment: How do you know this? Could it be that this char is just the result of cutting and pasting out of the chrome tools?

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode urls. Always use url helpers when dealing with urls. Also don't provide absolute urls as jQuery thinks it is JSONP (notice the `callback=jQuery151022712289774790406_1298625531801` parameter in your request) while the response is only JSON:

```
function saveSetting(settingNameArg, settingValueArg) {
    $.post(
        '<%= Url.Action("SaveSetting", "Account") %>',
        { settingName: settingNameArg, settingValue: settingValueArg },
        function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        'json'
    );
}
```

Also notice that your function arguments are called `settingNameArg` and `settingValueArg` whereas inyour code you were using `settingName` and `settingValue`.

Comment: My function arguments are not called `settingNameArg` and `settingValueArg`. Are you saying they should be? Using those names makes no difference.

This function is in an external JS file, so server-side code is not available. But the appUrl variable is set similarly in a different file that does get processed by MVC. Should I make sure it omits the protocol, scheme, and hostname?

Comment: I think you may be on to something with the JSONP suggestion. What causes jQuery to think it needs to append that callback parameter? What should that url parameter look like? I tried it as /Account/SaveSetting and ../Account/SaveSetting and each results in the callback param.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
// The Actionresult is being called by an Ajax Call:
    public ActionResult SomePartial(Object model)
    {
    return Json(new { state="Success", date="some data" });
    }

//OnSuccess of the Ajax Call:
    function OnSuccess(ajaxContext) {
    var result = eval(ajaxContext);
    if (result.state == "Success") {
    console.log(result.data)
    }
            else {
                // ERRORS
            }

        }
```

this returns a valid json object and displays it:)

also nb to validate your json http://jsonlint.com/